# Computing symmetric form of certain polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, symmetric-polynomials

I would like to know the best way to calculate the following.

Let $P(u,v,s,t)$ be a polynomial such that is invariant under permutation of $u\leftrightarrow s$ AND $v\leftrightarrow t$, that is $P(u,v,s,t)=P(s,t,u,v)$

This polynomial can be written as an algebraic combination of these elementary symmetric polynomials: $\{u+s,us,v+t,vt\}$.

An easy example is: $u^2 + s^2 = (u+s)^2 - 2us$.

But if I have $s^n t+u^n v$ things get more complicated (even for $n=1$).

I need to compute this "symmetric form" of a bunch of polynomials, so I would like to know how can I do it with software.

I tried with Maple but it cannot handle  $u\leftrightarrow s$ AND $v\leftrightarrow t$ (at the same time).

In case it is relevant to the context, these polynomials are functions on the Jacobian $J$ of a hyperelliptic curve of genus $2$. So these are functions in the function field $k(J)$ where the generic point of $J$ is $\{(u,v),(s,t)\}$.

Thanks

Comment: "This polynomial can be written as an algebraic combination of these elementary symmetric polynomials: $\{u+s,us,v+t,vt\}$.". No, it cannot.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Yes I was seeing that. The function field of the Jacobian consists of functions of the form $u+s, us, \tfrac{t-v}{s-u},  \tfrac{sv-ut}{s-u}$ and this function lives in the function field generated by those functions. Do you think including these rational functions makes more sense to express $P$ in terms of this basis?

Comment: Interesting. I don't even see how to write $st+uv$ (your function for $n=1$) in terms of these four functions. But I don't know any algorithms for this; I'm just eyeballing.

Comment: Okay, I see: If $a = u+s$, $b = us$, $c = \dfrac{t-v}{s-u}$ and $d = \dfrac{sv-ut}{s-u}$, then $st + uv = a^2c + ad - 2bc$ and $s^2 t + u^2 v = a^3c + a^2d - \left(2d+3ac\right) b$ and $s^3 t + u^3 v = a^4c + a^3d - \left( 4 a^2 c + 3 a d - 2 b c \right) b$. Looks like there is some recurrence to guess here.

Comment: I'm impressed, @darijgrinberg. How'd you come up with those? My scratch work didn't get me anywhere at all!

Comment: I took $s, a, c, d$ as constants and used them to solve for $u, t, v$. Then, I expanded $s^n t + u^n v$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and manually rewrote every appearance of $s \left(a-s\right)$ as $b$. Not a great general theory behind this, just handwork.

Comment: Ah, right. Of course, $s$ and $u$ are the roots of the monic polynomial $X^2 - aX + b$; thus, the polynomials $p_n = s^n t + u^n v$ satisfy the Fibonacci-like recurrence $p_n = a p_{n-1} - b_{n-2}$. Thus, if $p_0$ and $p_1$ are polynomials in $a, b, c, d$, then so is every $p_n$. But $p_0$ and $p_1$ are polynomials in $a, b, c, d$ indeed: namely, $p_0 = 2d-ac$ and $p_1 = a^2 c + ad - 2bc$.

Comment: Nice! That first sentence ("and used them to solve for...") was where i got stuck. The general recurrence is great. :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg If you want you can copy paste your relevant comments and I can put is as an answer.

Comment: @EduardoRuizDuarte: Done (minus a typo in the formula for $p_0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every polynomial $P$ satisfying $P\left(  u,v,s,t\right)  =P\left(
s,t,u,v\right)  $ can be written as a polynomial in the $u+s,us,v+t,vt$. And I
am not sure if every such polynomial can be written as a rational function in
the $u+s,us,\dfrac{t-v}{s-u},\dfrac{sv-ut}{s-u}$ either. But your polynomials
$s^{n}t+u^{n}v$ can be written in the latter form. Here is how:

Set $a=u+s$, $b=us$, $c=\dfrac{t-v}{s-u}$ and $d=\dfrac{sv-ut}{s-u}$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}\left(s,t,u,v\right)$. Set
$p_{n}=s^{n}t+u^{n}v$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, it is easy to check (by
straightforward computation) that
\begin{align*}
p_{0}  & =2d+ac;\\
p_{1}  & =a^{2}c+ad-2bc.
\end{align*}
Next, I claim that
\begin{equation}
p_{n}=ap_{n-1}-bp_{n-2}
\label{1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
for each $n\geq2$.

[*Proof of \eqref{1}:* Let $n\geq2$. Then, $p_{n}=s^{n}t+u^{n}v$ and similarly
$p_{n-1}=s^{n-1}t+u^{n-1}v$ and $p_{n-2}=s^{n-2}t+u^{n-2}v$. But
straightforward computation shows that $as-b=s^{2}$ and $au-b=u^{2}$. Now,
\begin{align*}
& a\underbrace{p_{n-1}}_{=s^{n-1}t+u^{n-1}v}-b\underbrace{p_{n-2}}
_{=s^{n-2}t+u^{n-2}v}\\
& =a\left(  \underbrace{s^{n-1}}_{=ss^{n-2}}t+\underbrace{u^{n-1}}_{=uu^{n-2}
}v\right)  -b\left(  s^{n-2}t+u^{n-2}v\right)  \\
& =a\left(  ss^{n-2}t+uu^{n-2}v\right)  -b\left(  s^{n-2}t+u^{n-2}v\right)
\\
& =ass^{n-2}t+auu^{n-2}v-bs^{n-2}t-bu^{n-2}v\\
& =\underbrace{\left(  ass^{n-2}t-bs^{n-2}t\right)  }_{=s^{n-2}\left(
as-b\right)  t}+\underbrace{\left(  auu^{n-2}v-bu^{n-2}v\right)  }
_{=u^{n-2}\left(  au-b\right)  v}\\
& =s^{n-2}\underbrace{\left(  as-b\right)  }_{=s^{2}}t+u^{n-2}
\underbrace{\left(  au-b\right)  }_{=u^{2}}v=\underbrace{s^{n-2}s^{2}}
_{=s^{n}}t+\underbrace{u^{n-2}u^{2}}_{=u^{n}}v\\
& =s^{n}t+u^{n}v=p_{n}.
\end{align*}
This proves \eqref{1}.]

From $p_{0}=2d+ac$ and $p_{1}=a^{2}c+ad-2bc$, we conclude that $p_{0}$ and
$p_{1}$ are polynomials in $a,b,c,d$. Therefore, by strong induction, we can
conclude that each $p_{n}$ (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$) is a polynomial in
$a,b,c,d$. (Indeed, \eqref{1} shows that if $p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n-2}$ are
polynomials in $a,b,c,d$, then so is $p_{n}$.)

Comment: This is great Darij.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer rests on a misreading of the question; see comments to see why. I'm leaving it because I think it may nonetheless prove useful to someone at some point.**

First step: symmetrize.,

You've got $P(u, v, s, t) = P(s, v, u, t)$, so apply that and rewrite
$P$ as the average of those two. Applying this to the case you asked about, this turns
$$
st + uv
$$
into
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left([st + uv] + [ut + sv]  \right).
$$
Then do that again with the $v$-to-$t$ symmetry:
$$
\frac{1}{4} \left([st + uv] + [ut + sv] + [sv + ut] + [uv + st]  \right).
$$

At this point, everywhere you have a term $u^k s^\ell t$, you've also got $u^k s^\ell v$. So gather up each $u^k s^\ell$ term, and its coefficient will be some expression that's symmetric in $v$ and $t$.

Then (using the method outlined below), rewrite each $u^k s^\ell$ term (leaving its coefficient in $v$ and $t$ untouched); then, using the same method, rewrite each $v^k t^\ell$ term similarly, leaving the $s$-and-$u$ part untouched. Then you're done!

You can write out the relevant items like $1, us + us, u^2 + s^2, u^2s + s^2 u, u^3s + s^3 u, u^2 s^2 + s^2 u^2, \ldots$ in terms of the given functions, and do this once and for all. 
$$
1 = (u+s)^0 \\
us + su  = 2 * us \\
u^2 + s^2 = (u+s)^2 - us
u^2s + s^2 u = us(s + u) \\
u^3 s + s^3 u =usu ( u^2 + s^2) = su( (u+s)^2 - us )
$$
and pretty soon you start to notice some patterns. If we denote by $P(n, k)$ the polynomial $u^n s^k + s^n u^k$, then there's a recurrence:
$$
P(n, k) = \begin{cases}
(us)^r \cdot P(n-r, k-r) & \text{for $r = min(n, k) > 0$}\\
P(n, k) = (u+s)^n - Q(n) & \text{when $k= 0$}\\
P(n, k) = (u+s)^n - Q(k) & \text{when $n= 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $Q(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ defined as
$$
Q(n, k) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} {n \choose i} u^i k^{n-i}.
$$
i.e., it's just the binomial expansion of $(u+s)^n$ without the $u^n$ and $s^n$ terms.

Applying this recurrence to each symmetric pair of terms in your polynomial will rewrite the $P(n, k)$ as an algebraic combination of powers of $u+s$ and $us$  (or similarly for $v+t$ and $vt$).

**Post-comment addition**
I've already showed that $st + uv$ is the same as 
$$
\frac{1}{4} \left([st + uv] + [ut + sv] + [sv + ut] + [uv + st]  \right).
$$
Gathering powers of $u$ and $s$ we have
$$
4(st + uv) = s(2t + 2v) + u(2t + 2v) = 2(s+u)(t+v).
$$
so that 
$$
st + uv = \frac{1}{2} \left ( (s+u)(t+v) \right).
$$

Comment: Dear John, thank you for your detailed answer, but I am not seeing how to mix both $u\leftrightarrow s$ and $t\leftrightarrow v$. The function $st+uv$ has these symmetries, what you showed me was only dealing with one symmetry, in this case $u\leftrightarrow s$. What I am not seeing? What is then the symmetric representation of $st+uv$

Comment: See post-comment addition. You start by symmetrizing in both $us$ and $tv$. Then organize as a polynomial in $u$ and $s$ (with coeffs being $t$-$v$ polynomials). In the case you asked about, things are particularly simple.

Comment: Ooops. Ignore all of that, and indeed, all of my answer. I mis-read that it was invariant under swaps of $u$ and $s$ and ALSO invariant under swaps of $t$ and $v$, rather than merely being invariant under the action of swapping both pairs at the same time.

Comment: Somebody pointed out above that these functions cannot be expressed in that "basis", so I was wondering, since these functions are functions in the function field of something that has generators $ u+s, us, \tfrac{t-v}{s-u}, \tfrac{sv-ut}{s-u}$ which respect the symmetries already mentioned, I think , then the representation will requiere these rational polynomials.

Comment: Perhaps so; best of luck.